# How to sort lines by the variable name in alphabetical order in Intellij?

Tags: java, sorting, variables, intellij-idea, formatting

So let's say I declare my variables like this:

```
String cVariable;
Integer eVariable;
boolean dVariable;
```

Is there a way that when I do a `Sort Lines` in Intellij it format the code like this (variable alphabetical order):

```
String cVariable;
boolean dVariable;
Integer eVariable;
```

Sort Lines seems to order variables with there type name like this:

```
boolean dVariable;
Integer eVariable;
String cVariable;
```

but that's not what I want...

Answer (score 1):

You can specify order as "Order by name" for each matching rule in Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java | Arrangement. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-java.html for reference

Comment: I don't know if I do it wrong but I tried to put order by name to all the rule and when I try Code | Reformat Code it does nothing...

Comment: worked for me on 2022.3.2 RC and 2023.1 EAP with your example and Matching Rule # 18 (just "field") set with Order as "order by name", triggered by Code | Rearrange code

Comment: after 'Code | Reformat code' you can press another shortcut (cmd+alt+shift+L on mac e.g., there's a hint appearing) and place a checkbox for Code | Rearrange code so it will rearranging by default

Comment: I used this one since all my variables have public in front of them.

Answer (score 0):

I used quickfix's answer but here is a screenshot.
I used this one since all my variables have public in front of them

[image]